# How to search within a website using python requests module and returning the response page?

Tags: python, search, web-scraping, web, python-requests

I want to retrieve data from a website named as myip.ms. I'm using requests to send data to form and then I want the response page back to me. When I run the script it returns the same page (homepage) in response. I want the next page using the query I provide. I'm new in WebScraping. Here's the code I'm using to achieve this.
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus
payload={
'name':'educationmaza.com',
'value':'educationmaza.com',
}
payload=urlencode(payload)
r=requests.post("http://myip.ms/s.php",data=payload)
infile=open("E://abc.html",'wb')
infile.write(r.content)
infile.close()

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but it appears that when interacting with the webpage, the post is processed by jQuery, which `requests` does not do well with. 
As such, you would have to use the Selenium module to interact with it. 
The following code will execute as desired:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

driver.get("https://myip.ms/s.php")
driver.find_element_by_id("home_txt").send_keys('educationmaza.com')
driver.find_element_by_id("home_submit").click()

html = driver.page_source

infile=open("stack.html",'w') 
infile.write(html) 
infile.close()
```

You will have to install the Selenium package, as well as [Phantom.JS](http://phantomjs.org). 
I have tested this code, and it works fine. Let me know if you need any further help!